# View assembly code produced from compiling VS 2010 C#.net?

Tags: c#, .net

I found a thread on here detailing how to view assembly code produced for VS C++, but I cannot seem to find a way in which I can view the assembly for C#.net code?

Is this possible? It doesnt appear to be as simple as the c++ version.

Thank you in advance

Comment: C# does NOT produce Assembly code but so-called IL code - are you asking how to see the IL code or do you really want the assembly (which is only available after JITing) ?

Comment: Ah I think that must have been something I came across. Does the IL code get output of C# by default, or do I have to set certain settings? Then I have to use Microsoft Dissembler to view it as assembly?

Comment: IL is what the .NET compilers output.

Comment: @user997112 you can take the result of C# compiler (EXE or DLL...) and open it in Reflector or ILDasm - these will display the IL code... another option is to debug the result in VS - the debugger can show IL code too...

Comment: @Oded, I meant do I have to set various settings for VS2010 to actually output the IL as a file, so that I can use another program to  view the IL as assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see a disassembled version of the IL produced by compiling a .NET code base by using a dissembler such as Reflector or ILDasm.

These show you the Intermediate Language that the code gets compiled into.

The .NET assemblies (**not** the same as assembly code) do get jitted later on to native code, though you can also use [ngen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx) to generate the native code before hand.

Comment: Hey oded, so I need to download Reflector. Do I need to change any configurations in visual studio in order to produce the output required to enter into Reflector?

Comment: You can use ILDASM - it will be on your computer if you Visual Studio or Windows SDK installed. There are also _many_ disassembles for .NET out there, free and otherwise (Reflector is pay for).

Answer (score 0):

you can take the result of C# compiler or **ANY .NET EXE/DLL** and open it for example in Reflector (commercial) or ILDasm (free) - these will display the IL code.

Another option is to debug the result in VS - the debugger can show IL code too.

Some links:

- http://www.reflector.net/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

IF you really want Assembler code (similar to the C++ result) then you can use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx together with any Disassembler.

Answer (score 0):

.NET languages don't directly produce ASM through compilation, they produce CIL, which is interpreted by the .NET runtime into assembly instructions using JIT compilation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language for details.

It *is* possible to produce a native binary from C# using [NGEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx) to produce a machine specific binary, which is generally used to improve applicaiton start-up times, but you're going to be better off looking at at the IL.

Answer (score 0):

Reflector was nice, but was taken over by RedGate and is no longer free.
But Telerik has an awesome free tool called JustDecompile (http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx)

It will even create a Visual Studio solution for the assembly.

We are still talking IL disassembly here.  If you want to see the native code, I believe you can display that in the Visual Studio debugger.